# h:outputText rendered if value appears in list

Tags: jsf

Just wondering if it's possible, without looping through a list, to check if a particular value appears in it?

I have a list of person details, Name, Age, D.O.B, etc, and based on a particular date of birth I will render some outputText. I do loop through the list in order to populate a table, but I want the outputText appearing outside of this table so I'm a little unsure as to how to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: you can build a new method that will do `mylist.contains(myobject)` or do i from EL expression directly

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing a method in your managed bean that will perform the logic and return a boolean.  You can then refer to this method in an EL expression.

```
public boolean isDateOfBirthFoshizzle() {
   //do business logic to check if DOB of any persons is foshizzle
   return retVal;
}
```

And in your EL expression

```
<h:outputText value="Someone is foshizzle" rendered="#{managedBean.isDateOfBirthFoshizzle()}" />
```